# quering an external oracle db in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, caching

I have a website which useses a mysql database for its whole operation . But for a new requirement i need to query a external oracle database( used by other component) and compile a list of items and display in a page in the website. How is it possible to connect to a external database just for rendering a single page.

And is it possible to cache the queried result for say 1 month before invalidating the cache and get the updated list of items. i dont want query the external  oracle db for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a monthly job that just copies the data from the Oracle database into the MySQL database ?

Comment: my doubt is, how will i connect to the oracle from my rails application. i do not want that oracle db details in the database.yml file. Just create a connection from a ruby file and query the oracle database. And monthly job from the rails app possible?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Myers, a simple solution is to accept a data feed. For example, a cron job could pull data from the Oracle database at defined intervals, say daily or weekly, and then insert the data into your web application's local MySQL database. The whole process could be essentially transparent to your web application. The caching interval, or how long you go between feeds, would be up to you.

I'll also point out that this could be an opportunity for an API that would more readily support sharing of data between applications. This would, of course, be more work than a simple data feed, but has the possibility of being more useful to more people.